# C# forwardonly string.replace

Tags: c#, string

I have to replace 2 double-quotes with 1 double-quote.

But I want it to be forward only, so if there are 4 double-quote, I want 2 double-quotes back.

string.replace() will give only 1 double-quote back, since it starts over from 0th index to search for 2 double-quotes again.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am I missing the point? I ask because the simple

```
string s = "\"\"Test.\"\"";
string t = s.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + s);
Console.WriteLine("After: " + t);
```

just output

```
Before: ""Test.""
After: "Test."
```

and

```
string u = "\"\"\"\"";
string v = w.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + u);
Console.WriteLine("After: " + v);
```

just output

```
Before: """"
After: ""
```

on my console. Please show us what you already have, the output it is producing, and the output as you want it because as I read your question, the above is fulfilling your request.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I guess I was not thinking straight. I was using Trim() in addition to replace() which was messing my final output. Your answer helped me realize the mistake. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Your statement doesn't seem to be correct, a string of four double-quotes replacing two double-quotes with one results in a string of two double-quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine("\"\"\"\"".Replace("\"\"", "\""));
```

produces

```
""
```

Actually, it doesn't make sense performance wise for `Replace` to restart searching for matches at index 0. When the first match is found and replaced we know that no matches is in the previous substring.

Comment: Gave you +1 because Jason's original answer did not include four quotes in a row. :)

Comment: @Sapph - thanks, I thought I would beat him on that, him fumbling with `"Test."` and all :)